# Visual Studio Code php inteliphense problem

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

**I have a class with 2 functions:**

- 1 function call another with $this-> in same class
- **Problem** is visual studio code because say `Undefined method 'setCookieCountCart'. inteliphense(1013)` but the functions are defined corectly and code work

```php
class SmartAppIndexController extends \SmartModExtLib\FrontendShared\AbstractController {


    public function Run() {

        $this->setCookieCountCart($cntProducts);

    }

     private function setCookieCountCart($cnt) : void {
           //-- code...
           return;
     }
}
```

[image: This are the extensions i use in visual studio code]

[image: There is the error]

Comment: Have you tried to restart vscode? Can you provide the logs for that extension?

Comment: i do... but same thing happened, can you tell me how to show you the log ?

Comment: The vscode output window should have a select input to see logs. There should be logs from extensions in general and logs from the intelephense.

Comment: Only these appear: `[Info  - 9:20:47 AM] Writing state to c:\Users\BoBiTza\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\feb10b1fbebdc161c57e1b9919635f6d\bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client\667cf2d1.
[Info  - 9:20:47 AM] Indexing started.
[Info  - 9:20:47 AM] Wrote state in 0.5s.
[Info  - 9:20:48 AM] Indexing ended. 17 files indexed in 0s.`

Comment: Maybe this ? `[2021-10-07 09:32:23.483] [exthost] [error] TypeError: Cannot read private member from an object whose class did not declare it` But class is declared: class SmartAppIndexController extends \SmartModExtLib\FrontendShared\AbstractController {

Answer (score 0):

The `setCookieCountCart` is declared as private in the class `SmartAppIndexController`. A private method can only be accessed inside its class. Change it to public or call your `Run()` instead since it's already public.

If you are extending `SmartAppIndexController` in another class, it will also work if the method is protected.

Comment: I make it public same problem..